# How to preserve dos text file encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, newline

I have written a small nodejs script for automating something Basically, all it does is:

1. Read and create a js object from file1
2. Read file2 line by line, find and replace some strings based on the previously created object.
3. Write that line to a new file.

---

While all of the above works, the formatting in the new file is different from that of the original file. I'm under the impression that the file being read is in dos format while the file being written is in unix format, but I'm not certain.

I would like to preserve all the escape characters as is. What extra should I do?

**main.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');

// get the file names from command line
var micrFileMappings = process.argv[2];
var inputFile = process.argv[3];

var micrObject = {};

// read the first file and create the object.
// the first file format is:
// 121212:2323232,
// 345353:2325646,...

var readMicrFile = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream(micrFileMappings),
  console: false
});

readMicrFile.on('line', function(line) {
  var currentLineArray = line.split(":");
  var key = currentLineArray[0];
  var value = currentLineArray[1];

  //populate the object
  micrObject[key] = value;
});


// read the file that is to be processed line by line
var rd = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(inputFile),
    console: false
});


rd.on('line', function(line) {

    var existingID = line.substring(2, 11);

    if (micrObject.hasOwnProperty(existingID)) {
        line = line.replace(existingID, micrObject[existingID]);
    }

    // write line by line to the new file
    fs.appendFile('processed.txt', line, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            // append failed
        } else {
            // done
        }
    });

});
```

My original file looks like this:

**od -c original.txt**

```
...
...
...
0002720                       5   6   0   0   1   5   1   0   0   5   6
                              5   6   0   0   1   5   1   0   0   5   6
0002740   0   3   2   3   4   B   r   u   h   a   t       B   e   n   g
          0   3   2   3   4   B   r   u   h   a   t       B   e   n   g
0002760   a   l   u   r   u       M   a   h   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
          a   l   u   r   u       M   a   h   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0003000   0   0   0   6   7   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   4   4   5
          0   0   0   6   7   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   4   4   5
0003020   4   0   0                                                    
          4   0   0                                                    
0003040                                          \r  \n
                                                 \r  \n
0003054
```

But my output file looks like below:

```
...
...
...
0001160   2   2   5   6   0   0   0   2   2   9   1   1   0            
0001200   0   2   5   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   6   3   8   K
0001220   u   m   a   r   a       S   w   a   m   y                    
0001240                                                                
0001260                               5   6   0   0   1   5   1   0   0
0001300   5   6   0   3   2   3   4   B   r   u   h   a   t       B   e
0001320   n   g   a   l   u   r   u       M   a   h   0   0   0   0   0
0001340   0   0   0   0   0   6   7   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   4
0001360   4   5   4   0   0                                            
0001400                                                
0001414
```

If you notice, the escape characters `\r` `\n` go missing. How do I preserve this?

Comment: By any chance could you link to `original.txt` or a small similar example?

Comment: @ExplosionPills - I'm not sure if I can share the exact copy of the text file online, but let me see if I can get a simplified sample.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at a [simplified source of readline.js](https://github.com/maleck13/readline/blob/master/readline.js) (This is not the [current version](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/04ae4862e670a8849454e6d8db4d8f73d0492190/lib/readline.js#L408)) you will see that 10(=='\r') and 13(=='\n') are not included in the buffer that's sent in the line event. I'm afraid you'll need a different library or modify the source to include it.

You can copy the simplified above library and add between line 35 and line 36

```
      lineBuffer[lineLength] = data[i]; // Buffer new line data.
      lineLength++;
```

and that will have desired effect.

Comment: Ah! This makes sense. So basically, you're saying that: I copy and save the entire readline.js locally, include the two lines you've suggested and then ```var readline = require('/path/to/modified/readline.js');``` instead. Am I correct?

Comment: yes, it should work. basically you are adding also those characters to the buffer that is past to the `line` event.